# Cut out of a solid overlay to display a peek of image/element underneath

Tags: css

I have a complex grid of many images.  Most images have different sizes.  I've successfully created a uniform overlay that is generated for each image that appears on hover.  Part of the design requires a line through the overlay that shows a peek of the image below.  See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roiPw.jpg) for an idea of what I need.

Initially I thought I could just use a bottom-border to create a line and set it to transparent to display the bottom-most element (i.e. the image) but since the overlay's background is set to #fff, the transparency only showed the white of the overlay (DUH!)

Is there any way to use CSS to cut through the overlay and let the image element peek through?

Here's the HTML (image example above doesn't include "Shop Now"):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="module" id="img-1">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />    
        <a href="#" class="overlay">        
            <p class="tagline">Test</p>
            <p class="cta italics">Shop Now</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="module" id="img-2">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />    
        <a href="#" class="overlay">        
            <p class="tagline">Test</p>
            <p class="cta italics">Shop Now</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.module {
    position: relative;
}
.module img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0; 
}
.tagline,
.cta {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.tagline {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black; /*Current Placeholder for the cut-out I need*/
    bottom: 42%;
}
.cta {
    top:75%;
}
.overlay:hover .tagline,
.overlay:hover .cta,
.overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.overlay` just need to have a solid background (`#fff` in this case). You can try using `box-shadow` trick. The `background` of the `.overlay` should be transparent by default, we need some inner element (such as a `:before` element) to render the tagline, this element should also have a transparent background, for the remaining white region, we need to use `box-shadow` with as large a value of `spread` as possible:

```
.overlay:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:42%;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 100vw #fff;
}
```

Note that the `background` of `.overlay` should be set back to `transparent` (or simply remove it).

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y25P3/).

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting it.  I do need both the ```.tagline``` and ```.cta```, is there a way to have 2 contents? can I do something like ```content:'<p class="tagline">Test</p><p class=cta italics">Shop Now</p>';```

Comment: @user3486605 why do you need to put the content inside the `:before`? Note that the `:before` is just used to render the visual appearance, all the content should be placed inside the HTML code.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood when you said, "we need some inner element (such as a :before element) to render the tagline," Rereading, it I'm like duh!

Comment: You're a genius! That totally worked! Thank you so so much! I don't have a high enough reputation to vote you up, but I will as soon as I can!

Comment: @user3486605 you're welcome, it's just a simple trick with `box-shadow`, everyone can learn it.